# get the text of a headline using php dom

Tags: php, dom

I have that HTML code

```
$html =  "<h1 id='h1>hhhh111</h1>"
        ."<h1 id='h2'>hhhh222</h1>"
        ."<h1 id='h3'>hhhh333</h1>";
```

I want to print "hhhh222" using DOM and PHP

I am trying that one -

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('h1')[1];
```

But not working so please help to print "hhhh222" using DOM and PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('h1')->item(1)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: Then ask a question with the code you've tried. Don't hijack this answer

Comment: @user2727841 What problem you faced?

Comment: check it. $html = "<h1 id='h1' >hhhh111</h1><h1 id='h2' >hhhh222</h1><h1 id='h3' >hhhh333</h1>"; $dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html); echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('h1')->item(1)->nodeValue; but nothing get printed.

Comment: @RinkuYadav You Can accept the answer if that really worked for You. Also, that'll make others to easily find the soultion.

Comment: @user2727841 Please Check DOM extension is installed/enabled with your PHP version.

Comment: I've wamp server 2.1.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44268/discussion-between-jenson-m-john-and-user2727841)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this:

```
$html = "<h1 id='h1' >hhhh111</h1>
<h1 id='h2' >hhhh222</h1>
<h1 id='h3' >hhhh333</h1>";
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
$div = $xpath->query("//*[@id='h2']")->item(0)->nodeValue;
      echo $div;
```

Comment: Yeah. That too will Solve the problem..:)